# how to get the last result after looping at C#

Tags: c#

Hello i'm new at C# and programming so i get stuck for hours to get the last result from my looping result
here my code :

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string merek = string.Empty;
        // i wanted to get the last value which is 13 R DLX DG M/T
        string str = "DAIHATSU.ALL NEW XENIA.13 R DLX DG M/T";
        // Taking a string 
        char[] spearator = { '.', '.' }; 

        // using the method 
        String[] strlist = str.Split(spearator);

        foreach(String s  in strlist) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

this the point

```
the result is
DAIHATSU
ALL NEW XENIA
13 R DLX DG M/T
// i wanted to get the last value which is 13 R DLX DG M/T
string str = "DAIHATSU.ALL NEW XENIA.13 R DLX DG M/T";
```

i'm really appreciate for any help thank you.

Comment: `var lastItem = strlist[strlist.Length - 1];`

Comment: By the way, you don't need to specify two dots as separator, one is enough. You can use an array to specify (for instance) that both a dot and a comma can be separators, in any order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `for` loop. You can simply print the last part using the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(strlist[strlist.Length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IEnumerable<T>.Last()`:

`var last = strlist.Last();`

Remember to include Linq:

`using System.Linq;`

Comment: Its not advisable to refer `Linq` for just one simple operation.

Comment: I never saw that advice, do you have a link?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your title question, you are looking for the last value after looping.

You can access it directly from your string array.

```
strlist[strlist.Length - 1];
```

If there is any valid reason to go through the array, another alternative would be this

```
string latest = "";
foreach(String s  in strlist) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    latest = s;
}
// After the loop,  the latest variable will have the value you are looking for.
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using another Linq cal, you could try using the "IsLast" property from the SmartEnumerable Extension from Jon Skeet's old but reliable MiscUtil. Here's a link to a port into modern .net

https://github.com/jaredthirsk/JTForks.MiscUtil/blob/master/JTForks.MiscUtil/Collections/SmartEnumerable.cs